# Computational cost for mutable state-based vs immutable event-based data model

Tags: java, android, performance, list, immutability

Apologies in advance, this is a long one. I'm currently creating a scoreboard app for the sport of [Snooker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snooker). The basic rules are that a player must pot a red ball and a coloured ball in alternating fashion until no reds remain. After that, the remaining colour balls are potted in value order. At first I used a traditional mutable Java data model like this:

```
public class Player {
    public enum PlayerPosition { PLAYER_ONE, PLAYER_TWO };

    String name;
    int score;
    int currentBreak;
}

public class Frame {
    Player playerOne, playerTwo;
    PlayerPosition breakingPlayer, playerAtTable;
    int redsOnTable;
    Ball[] remainingColours = new Ball[] { YELLOW, GREEN, BROWN, BLUE, PINK, BLACK };
}
```

So as balls are potted, the value of that ball is added to a `Player`'s `score` and `redsOnTable` is reduced. The issue with this is while the total of the break is stored, the order of the balls potted is not. However, by adding the order of balls potted, I'm now introducing redundant data into the data model as `redsOnTable` can now be calculated by looking at the order of the balls potted.

So I then began wondering if the `Frame` can instead be seen as a sequence of events, e.g.

- Red ball potted
- Black ball potted
- Red ball potted
- *End of break*
- Red ball potted
- ...

from which all additional information (e.g. `redsOnTable`, a player's highest break, total remaining on the table) can be calculated by iterating through this list of events, the disadvantage being a much greater computational cost due to iterating through this list every time a statistic needs to be retrieved. I did attempt something like this, splitting each player's breaks out as a `List<List<Ball>>`:

```
@AutoValue public abstract class Break implements Parcelable {
    public abstract List<Ball> getBallOrder();
    public static Break create(List<Ball> balls) { return new AutoValue_Break(balls); }
}


@AutoValue public abstract class Frame implements Parcelable {
    public abstract int getStartingReds();
    public abstract List<Break> getBreakHistory();
    public abstract PlayerPosition getPlayerPositionAtTable();
    public abstract PlayerPosition getBreakingPlayer();
    public abstract Builder toBuilder();
}
```

but this lead to a bug where I couldn't determine if the game was on the final colour run (yellow, green, etc), and a very messy fix, so I want to move to storing all events in a single `List<Event>`. This list will currently be read 5 times per refresh (determining the player at the table, getting player scores (x2), getting the total left on the table, getting the lowest value ball remaining on the table), but I can probably refactor it so I can grab all this information on a single iteration.

So my question boils down to this:

- Is the additional computational cost required for an immutable event-based data model likely to have a significant impact on performance on a recent low-end Android phone compared to a traditional mutable data model?
- Is there a more efficient class than `ArrayList` I could be using for storing and iterating through these events (i.e. skip to next `EndOfBreak` event, get number of Red ball events in the list). Assume this list can easily go to 100+ events in a long safety battle.
- Are there any other considerations I need to keep in mind with long lists that are frequently iterated through?

---

**Edit:** About that Colour Run bug. Once all the reds have been potted, the remaining colour balls must be potted in value order, and do not get replaced back onto the table. There are a number of scenarios that can happen here:

1:

- Player one pots the last red
- Player one pots a colour (not a yellow)
- Player one does not pot yellow, end of break
- Player two must now hit the yellow

2:

- Player one pots the last red
- Player one misses their next shot (or fouls), end of break
- Player two must now hit the yellow

3:

- Player one pots the last red
- Player one pots a yellow, yellow put back on table
- Player one does not pot the yellow, end of break
- Player two must hit the yellow

So if we're going purely by potted order and not using an `EndOfBreak` event, this poses a problem as the next ball to pot **may or may not** be put back on the table.

- In scenario 1 we know that the yellow is the next ball to pot as the ball potted after final the red was not a yellow.
- In scenario 2, the last ball potted was a red, so we have to check if the final red was potted as part of this current break to determine if we're on the colour run or not. Not possible if we're only doing a ball countback without including `EndOfBreak` events.
- In scenario 3, the last ball potted is ambiguous as it is a yellow. How does the app know if the yellow is still on the table if we don't have `EndOfBreak` information?

As I mentioned before, I did come up with a fix, but it was very cumbersome and still has a few edge cases where it doesn't work, which is why I want to include `EndOfBreak` as an event in this list.

Comment: How about a `HashMap<String,Integer>` where the key is the ball color and you increment the value everytime a ball is potted?. To get the count, all you would have to then do is `ballOrder.get("reds");`

Comment: Would this be a new `HashMap<>` for each break? Even so, that wouldn't preserve the order in which the balls were potted, and would still lead to the same colour run bug I mentioned. I'll edit my question to include details of that bug